# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, http, angular, typescript, observable

I have this part of code in my application

```js
addComment (body: Object): Observable<Comment[]> {
    //let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
    let bodyString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body || null ))
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

    return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl, bodyString, options) // ...using post request
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
}
```

When I try to add a comment in my application it throws an error as below:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/assets/comments.json 404 (Not Found)   
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
```

Someone can help me?

Fully SyntaxError stack:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (body.js:24)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (comment.service.ts:41)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:82)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.1301.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:363)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.1301.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:362)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.1301.Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:416)
```

Comment: Can we have a look at how you're calling `addComment` ?

Comment: Why do you stringify, then parse?

Comment: Can you attach the SyntaxError stack, to indicate which code line throws the error? And when `addComment` is invoked, what is the value of `this.model` object?

Comment: @shaochuancs the value of this.model is [object Object].

Comment: According to the stack, the SyntaxError origins from `Response.Body.json (body.js:24)` and `CatchSubscriber.selector (comment.service.ts:41)`. Which one appears in your code? And which line does it indicate?

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the exactly issue.

Just change:

```
error.json()
```

to

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))
```

Comment: Working Like a Charm !! :)

Answer (score 3):

You might have echoed something that starts with **C** like **Connected**
You should echo only json response and not any String in general!

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues. I found out that return type function from spring boot was not supported in Angular.
The return type of the function was `ResponseEntity<String>`.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new String("Some Message"));
```

I changed it to `ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage>` and modified the return as

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage("Some Message"));
```

And it worked.
The `ResponseMessage` class contained

```
  public class ResponseMessage {
  private String message;

  public ResponseMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

}
```

Thanks to Stackoverflow community. This is my first Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue when I attempt to send an empty body in the request. Can you confirm that the body being sent is not undefined?

You could try adding a condition around the post that checks if the body contains something before sending.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error when my php file contained connection successfull message. When i removed all echo commands expect that of json_encode(),i got it working So Make sure that in your php file there is only  echo of `echo json_encode($data)`

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this code

example

```
  addComment(user: ApiDashboard) {
   return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl,user).map(response => 
   response.json());
   }
```

you can try with

```
  addComment(user: Comment) {
   return this.http.post(this.commentsUrl,user).map(response => 
   response.json());
   }
```

here Comment is model file

for example

```
export class ApiDashboard {
id: string;
name: string;
price: number;
 }
```

- this case appears when you have printed some values in service file in my case

> service.ts

```
 private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
//console.error('An error occurred', error); 
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }
```

i commented console.log() then it may works fine can you try solution.